# How to convert %hex to chars in Tcl?

Tags: string, char, hex, tcl

I need some help in TCL. I have the following string as an example:

```
%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22video-container-direct%22%20style%3D%22position%3A%20relative%3Bpadding-bottom%3A%2056.6%25%3Bpadding-top%3A%2090px
%3Bheight%3A%200%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%22%3E%3Ciframe%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20scrolling%3D%E2%80%9Cno
%22%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fwww.vsports.pt%2Fembd%2F68680%2Fm%2F8856%2Fmaisf%2Fce1702fde64b1cf799dded7f1f3ab428%3Fautostart%3Dfalse%22%20
style%3D%22position%3A%20absolute%3Btop%3A0%3Bleft%3A%200%3Bwidth%3A%20100%25%3Bheight%3A%20100%25%3Bborder%3A0%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe
%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E
```

and I want to replace everything after % and removing the % of course. I mean, turning `%2F` to `/`, `%3D` to `=`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is using the [uri::urn](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/uri/urn-scheme.md) package from [tcllib](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/) (Should be installable via your OS's package manager):

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require uri::urn

set s "%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22video-container-direct%22%20style%3D%22position%3A%20relative%3Bpadding-bottom%3A%2056.6%25%3Bpadding-top%3A%2090px
%3Bheight%3A%200%3Boverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%22%3E%3Ciframe%20allowfullscreen%3D%22%22%20frameborder%3D%220%22%20scrolling%3D%E2%80%9Cno
%22%20src%3D%22%2F%2Fwww.vsports.pt%2Fembd%2F68680%2Fm%2F8856%2Fmaisf%2Fce1702fde64b1cf799dded7f1f3ab428%3Fautostart%3Dfalse%22%20
style%3D%22position%3A%20absolute%3Btop%3A0%3Bleft%3A%200%3Bwidth%3A%20100%25%3Bheight%3A%20100%25%3Bborder%3A0%22%3E%3C%2Fiframe
%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E"

puts [uri::urn::unquote $s]
```

Tcl 8.7 will let you do it with [`regsub`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/regsub.html) (URL decoding is even one of the examples, copied below):

```
# Match one of the sequences in a URL-encoded string that needs
# fixing, converting + to space and %XX to the right character
# (e.g., %7e becomes ~)
set RE {(\+)|%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})}

# Note that -command uses a command prefix, not a command name
set decoded [regsub -all -command $RE $string {apply {{- p h} {
    # + is a special case; handle directly
    if {$p eq "+"} {
        return " "
    }
    # convert hex to a char
    scan $h %x charNumber
    format %c $charNumber
}}}]

puts $decoded
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I would give. Doing that decoding before 8.7 was _messy_ (with a nasty mess of `regsub` and `subst` that always require careful testing when you write it) so it is far better to use a library function for that.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I got raspbian 10.9 currently running on raspberry pi. Current version for tcl is 8.6.9. I think I tried to install manually tcl 8.6.11 or tcl 8.7 alpha using other machines but the installation wasn't so perfect as if I installed using apt-get, so I decided to stick to the tcl 8.6.9 from stable release included with debian. As for the solution for my question, the package require urn::uri worked wonderfully. It said 1.0.3 and decoded the gibberished string. Thanks.